# What is a way to combine different images to form a single image?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I want to make a cartoon using face.jpg hair.jpg eyes.jpg and all other .jpg files of other facial features to make a single image of a cartoon. I know that i can draw lines,circles,ellipses etc. on image bitmap using its graphics object but is there a way to draw a image bitmap on a Graphics object?. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance, you can use [Graphics.DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.